# Two different interfaces and monitors for one application

Tags: c#, user-interface, monitor

I want to have two different user interfaces for a software so that, by executing the software, One is displayed on first monitor and another on second monitor. Is this possible? Can I distinguish between two monitors in the software? (The program is written in C# and Visual Studio).

Thank you...

Comment: Just open two instances of your application in place windows on different monitors.

Comment: Two monitors are connected to a computer. Opening two  instances of application on both monitors displays a single graphical interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code sample:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); 

// Set this variable to the desired monitor.
int indexMonitor = 1;

// Get all the available monitors/ screens
Screen[] sc = Screen.AllScreens; 

// Use the Bounds.Width and Bounds.Height of the monitor to display form2 on the second monitor.
form2.Left = sc[indexMonitor].Bounds.Width; 
form2.Top = sc[indexMonitor].Bounds.Height; 

// You modified the .Left and .Top of form2, so you will need to use the FormStartPosition.Manual
form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; 
form2.Show();
```

More information about the Screen clas: [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does it matter how monitors are connected to the system? (With HDMI,VGA ,... ).

Comment: @fidelroha No, that shouldn't matter.